# Clicking Back Browser UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue where by I click on a asp Button which opens up a UpdatePanel pop up with two other buttons on, to confirm or to cancel the submit request basically.

Now I do the follow:-

Click "Submit" then it opens up the popup (which is actually a UpdatePanel made to look like a popup) I then click on Cancel with performs a _Click to make the asp Panel within the UpdatePanel to .Visible = false. I then click on a different link and click my back button on my browser. The state of the page is with the popup on with the Confirm and Cancel buttons, but the buttons do not do anything once clicked.

Comment: Also, this is all done on the same page. So the link I click is calling the same page.

Comment: Do you have any code? This will help people with answering your question.